# Removing Wordpress Plugin Menu Item for a specific user

Tags: plugins, users, admin-menu, content-restriction

I want to remove certain dashboard menu times for a specific user. Now this menu consist of plugin menu items as well. One particular plugin I want to hide from the user is Contact Form 7.

Here is the code added to the functions.php file to hide the menu items:

```
function remove_menus()
{
    global $menu;
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    if($current_user->user_login == 'brian')
    {
        $restricted = array(__('Media'),
                            __('Links'),
                            __('Pages'),
                            __('Comments'),
                            __('Appearance'),
                            __('Plugins'),
                            __('Users'),
                            __('Tools'),
                            __('Settings'),
                    __('WPCF7')  //this does not work
        );
        end ($menu);
        while (prev($menu)){
            $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
            if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){unset($menu[key($menu)]);}
        }// end while
    }// end if
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menus');
```

Now everything listed in the code above here is hidden, except for the Contact Form 7 Plugin menu. How do I call the correct plugin name?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code you need:

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

if ( $current_user->user_login === 'brian' )
     remove_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpcf7_admin_menu', 9 );
```

Or if you want to retain your own code, use this:

```
function remove_menus()
{
    global $menu;
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    if($current_user->user_login == 'brian')
    {
        $restricted = array(__('Media'),
                            __('Links'),
                            __('Pages'),
                            __('Comments'),
                            __('Appearance'),
                            __('Plugins'),
                            __('Users'),
                            __('Tools'),
                            __('Settings'),
                    __('Contact')  //this does not work
        );
        end ($menu);
        while (prev($menu)){
            $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
            if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){unset($menu[key($menu)]);}
        }// end while
    }// end if
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menus');
```

I changed WPCF7 to Contact in the array.

Comment: thanks splashingpixels, appreciate your help just used the __('Contact').